# How to start SAMBA on MAC OS X from Terminal?

Tags: macos, cocoa, bash, terminal

I am trying to enable SAMBA (SMB) from terminal.

This enables AFP and File Sharing:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
```

But I want enable SMB too from terminal. How can I do that? I need this for MAC OS X (10.5, 10.6, 10.7).

P.S. Same effect if you go to System Preferences->Sharing->File Sharing->SMB (Windows) need to be enabled.

Comment: I'm quite sure you could somehow record an Automator action workflow thingie for this and run it. EDIT: Ignore that, you want to do it from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If you run the following:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist
```

The service will launch, although the GUI won't update (as you force loading the service, even if disabled).

You can also remove the Disabled flag from the file and have it load regularly.

---

You can also run `/usr/sbin/smbd` directly, as root.

Comment: Thanks. But first option won't work on Snow Leopard.Couldn't stat("/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.appl.smbd.plist"): No such file or directory.

Comment: @User1234 You mistyped the file name: `appl`

Comment: sorry. here it is  Couldn't stat("/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist"): But it works for Lion, I guess on Snow Leopard it is ddifferent. It doesn't update UI , but it is avalaible?

Comment: I guess on MAC OS X Snow Leopard it is com.apple.smb.server.preferences.plist

Comment: It's not working, it's displaying empty , that nothing is shared, when I try to connect from windows.

Comment: But when I'm doing it from GUI it works fine, do you have an idea?

Comment: @User1234 No, as I don't use SL anymore. Have you tired launching smbd directly? The LaunchDaemon doesn't do anything else anyway.

Comment: Yes I tried both. it's just displaying emtpy, no folders.. On Lion it won't work as well.. I need to start something, that GUI does

Answer (score 1):

On Snow Leopard it's `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/smbd.plist`